# Javascript - How do I capture and respond to a post?

Tags: javascript, html, post, xmlhttprequest, response

I am developing an application to respond to a punch out, but am missing something.  I can create the reponse XML document fine, but the receiving end is not seeing my response.  I have found hundreds of examples on the web about the post process, but cannot seem to figure out what the server is supposed to do to reply to the post.  If anyone can offer an example of the server side of this, that would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**
Here is the code that I have.  I did replace the SEND with a display to see what it was I am trying to send.  I am very new to this, so any insight would be helpful.

```
<script language="javascript">



var xmlhttp;
var xmlrtn;
<!-- Begin
  Stamp = new Date();
  year = Stamp.getYear();
  month = Stamp.getMonth() + 1;
  if (month < 10) {month = "0" + month;}
  ddate = Stamp.getDate();
  if (ddate < 10) {ddate = "0" + ddate;}
  if (year < 2000) year = 1900 + year;
  //document.write(year + "-" + month + "-" + ddate);
  timestamp = year + "-" + month + "-" + ddate;
  var Hours;
  var Mins;
  var Time;
  Hours = Stamp.getHours();
  Mins = Stamp.getMinutes();
  if (Mins < 10) {
   Mins = "0" + Mins;
  } 
  Secs = Stamp.getSeconds();
  if (Secs < 10) {Secs = "0" + Secs;}
  //document.write('T' + Hours + ":" + Mins + ":" + Secs);
  timestamp = timestamp + 'T' + Hours + ":" + Mins + ":" + Secs;
 // End -->

xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");   

 var o="&lt;";
 var c="/" + "&gt;"; 
 var tc="&lt;" + "/";
 var e="&gt;"; 
 var params=new Array();
 var xmlrtn = '';



function loadXML(xmlFile)
 {
   xmlhttp.async="false";
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=verify;
   xmlhttp.load(xmlFile);
   xmlObj=xmlhttp.documentElement;
 }

function verify()
 {
   // 0 Object is not initialized
   // 1 Loading object is loading data
   // 2 Loaded object has loaded data
   // 3 Data from object can be worked with
   // 4 Object completely initialized
   if (xmlhttp.readyState != 4)
  {
        return false;
  }
 }


</script>
</head>
<body>



 <script language="javascript">


//Read in XML file
 loadXML('https://www.americantexchem.com:9443/storefrontContent/attach/sample.xml');

 //Assign Variables
 var xmlver='?xml version="1.0"?';
 var doctype='!DOCTYPE cXML SYSTEM "http://xml.cxml.org/schemas/cXML/1.1.007/cXML.dtd"';

 xmlLang=xmlObj.getAttribute("xml:lang");

 var cxmltag=xmlObj.tagName;
 var cxmlval=' version="' + xmlObj.getAttribute("version") + '" payloadID="' + xmlObj.getAttribute("payloadID") + '"   timestamp="' + timestamp + '"';

 var resptag='Response';
 var statustag='Status code="200" text="success" ';
 var poutsrtag='PunchOutSetupResponse';
 var startpgtag='StartPage';
 var urltag='URL';
 var urlval='https://www.americantexchem.com:9443/storefrontCommerce/jsp/wynlogin.jsp';
 var srcurlval = xmlObj.childNodes(1).childNodes(0).childNodes(2).childNodes(0).firstChild.text; //URL content

 // post


  params[0] = o + xmlver + e;
  params[1] = o + doctype + e;
  params[2] = o + cxmltag;
  params[3] = cxmlval + e;
  params[4] = o + resptag + e;
  params[5] = o + statustag + c;
  params[6] = o + poutsrtag + e;
  params[7] = o + startpgtag + e;
  params[8] = o + urltag + e;
  params[9] = urlval;
  params[10] = tc + urltag + e;
  params[11] = tc + startpgtag + e;
  params[12] = tc + poutsrtag + e;
  params[13] = tc + resptag + e;
  params[14] = tc + cxmltag + e;

  for (var i in params) { 
           if (params.hasOwnProperty(i)) { 
           // var input = document.createElement('input'); 
               //   input.type = 'hidden'; 
                 // input.name = i; 
           //input.value = params[i]; 
              //    form.appendChild(input);
              xmlrtn = xmlrtn + params[i];  
    } 
   } 

 // alert (xmlObj.xml);
 document.write (xmlrtn);



 /*
  var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
  fileBool = fso.FileExists("C:\\out.xml");
  if(fileBool)
  {
   //document.write("Test-fileBool");
   fso.DeleteFile("C:\\out.xml",true);
  }

  var fso, s; 
    fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"); 
    s = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\\out.xml" , 8, true); 


  s.writeline (o + xmlver + e);
  s.writeline (o + doctype + e);
  s.writeline (o + cxmltag);
  s.writeline (cxmlval + e);
  s.writeline (o + resptag + e);
  s.writeline (o + statustag + c);
  s.writeline (o + poutsrtag + e);
  s.writeline (o + startpgtag + e);
  s.writeline (o + urltag + e);
  s.writeline (urlval);
  s.writeline (tc + urltag + e);
  s.writeline (tc + startpgtag + e);
  s.writeline (tc + poutsrtag + e);
  s.writeline (tc + resptag + e);
  s.writeline (tc + cxmltag + e);

//  s.writeline (xmlObj.xml); // the whole source xml document

 s.Close(); 

*/
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would help if you could show us whatever you have working -- if you have the client-side working, then show that -- we'll help you fill in what you don't have

Comment: Rather than dumping all your code, please post a [minimal test case](http://sscce.org/). For more on asking questions here on SO, read ["Writing the perfect question"](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints).

Answer (score 0):

This will depend a bit on your server side technology. Here is an example post using asp.net mvc.

http://blog.bobcravens.com/2009/11/ajax-calls-to-asp-net-mvc-action-methods-using-jquery/

Hope this helps getting you started

Bob